# How can I create multiple 'shell' under emacs

Tags: emacs

In emacs, I can create a shell using <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`.
But how can I create multiple shell?

I did

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`<kbd>RET</kbd>
2. <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`<kbd>RET</kbd>

It gives me back to shell in Step #1. How can I create multiple independent shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to rename your shell buffers:

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd>shell
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd>rename-buffer<kbd>RET</kbd>sh1<kbd>RET</kbd>
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd>shell

Now you have 2 shell windows, one named "sh1" and the other "*shell*".

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`shell`<kbd>RET</kbd>

```
(shell &optional BUFFER)
[snip]
If BUFFER exists but shell process is not running, make new shell.
If BUFFER exists and shell process is running, just switch to BUFFER.
```

- <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`<kbd>RET</kbd> :: Create a new shell or switch to
  an existing shell.
- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell`<kbd>RET</kbd> :: Ask for a
  buffer name, create a new shell if necessary and switch to that
  buffer.

An alternative is to use `term.el` with [multiterm](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.fr/2010/06/console-apps-in-emacs-with-multi-term.html).